# How to create Newsstand Magazine App using opensource framework or free tools?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, newsstand-kit

I would like to create an interactive iOS Newsstand Magazine app with features including page curl effect, direct to a page from contents table, double tab to get list of pages icon at bottom in a horizontal line, page with images and link to a web page inside Magazine that should open with Safari.

1. Is there any open source framework/tools (except Baker) or tutorial for free?.
2. Is it possible to get done everything using PageViewController?.
3. Is there also any restriction on number of pages in a Magazine app (either minimum or maximum pages per Magazine issue)?

Target Platform is iOS 6.0 and greater, Target device is iPad/iPad mini running on iOS 6.0 and greater.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a long journey to create a Newsstand App. You could also go the easy road and release your magazine through something like - http://uninkd.com.

Answer (score 2):

1. [This tutorial](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/) explain most of what you need to know. Need to be more specific about what open source tools you need.
2. Yes
3. Apple does not specify, but you *should* publish regularly.

Comment: Enrico, Thanks for your answer. Regarding the open source, I would like to have one that will bring everything what I need such as page curl and etc., Baker is best example for open source but it won't support page curl effect. So I am looking for similar tool with all the features I expect. Do you know any one? or any suggestion?

Comment: Although I haven't used it before, but page curl effect is included in the UIKit framework. You probably can use some UIView animation to achieve that.